# psql - read SQL file and output to CSV

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a SQL file `my_query.sql`:

```
select * from my_table
```

Using `psql`, I can read in this sql file:

`\i my_query.sql`

Or pass it in as an arg:

`psql -f my_query.sql`

And I can output the results of a query string to a csv:

`\copy (select * from my_table) to 'output.csv' with csv header`

Is there a way to combine these so I can output the results of a query from a SQL file to a CSV?

Comment: Have your tried anything?

Comment: nope nothing at all.

Comment: You mean something like running from the command line: `psql -f my_query.sql -d mydb` where `my_query.sql` contains your COPY statement?

Comment: no @KristoMagi the SQL query is just a regular old query, without any `copy` syntax.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: OSX is the operating system i am using

Comment: Something like `echo "\copy (``tr '\n;' ' ' < my_query.sql``) to 'output.csv' with csv header" | psql` in the shell. Works on Linux but as I know OSX is very similar. Probably you will need to change `\n` to `\r` (chencge double back quotes to single, just don know how to post it here).

Comment: I can not test it on OSX so I am not sure that it is a solution. Just try it and if it works then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Unfortunately there's no baked-in functionality for this, so you need a little bash-fu to get this to work properly.**

```
CONN="psql -U my_user -d my_db"
QUERY="$(sed 's/;//g;/^--/ d;s/--.*//g;' my_query.sql | tr '\n' ' ')"

echo "\\copy ($QUERY) to 'out.csv' with CSV HEADER" | $CONN
```

---

The `sed` fun removes all semicolons, comment lines, and end of line comments, and `tr` converts newlines to spaces (as mentioned in a comment by @abelisto):

```
-- my_query.sql
select *
from my_table
where timestamp < current_date -- only want today's records
limit 10;
```

becomes:

```
select * from my_table where timestamp < current_date limit 10
```

which then gets passed in to the valid `psql` command:

```
\copy (select * from my_table where timestamp < current_date) to 'out.csv' with csv header
```

---

Here's a script:

**`sql_to_csv.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
# sql_to_csv.sh

CONN="psql -U my_user -d my_db"
QUERY="$(sed 's/;//g;/^--/ d;s/--.*//g;' $1 | tr '\n' ' ')"
echo "$QUERY"

echo "\\copy ($QUERY) to '$2' with csv header" | $CONN > /dev/null
```

`./sql_to_csv.sh my_query.sql out.csv`

Comment: Thx for the response! However I needed to add a backslash to echo to make it work for me: `echo "\\\copy ($QUERY...`

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to take advantage of the shell's variable expansion capabilities:

```
psql -U my_user -d my_db -c "COPY ($(cat my_query.sql)) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER" > my_query_results.csv
```

Comment: When try this in OSX I get 'syntax error at or near "$" '.

Comment: Note i'm at the psql command line when I try this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a bash script.

dump_query_to_csv.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Takes an sql query file as an argument and dumps its results
# to a CSV file using psql \copy command.
#
# Usage:
#
#  dump_query_to_csv.sh <sql_query_file> [<csv_output_filesname>]

SQL_FILE=$1
[ -z $SQL_FILE ] && echo "Must supply query file" && exit
shift

OUT_FILE=$1
[ -z $OUT_FILE ] && OUT_FILE="output.csv" # default to "output.csv" if no argument is passed

TMP_TABLE=ttt_temp_table_xx # some table name that will not collide with existing tables

## Build a psql script to do the work
PSQL_SCRIPT=temp.psql

# create a temporary database table using the SQL from the query file
echo "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TMP_TABLE;CREATE TABLE $TMP_TABLE AS" > $PSQL_SCRIPT
cat $SQL_FILE >> $PSQL_SCRIPT
echo ";" >> $PSQL_SCRIPT

# copy the temporary table to the output CSV file
echo "\copy (select * from $TMP_TABLE) to '$OUT_FILE' with csv header" >> $PSQL_SCRIPT

# drop the temporary table
echo "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TMP_TABLE;" >> temp.sql

## Run psql script using psql
psql my_database < $PSQL_SCRIPT # replace my_database and add user login credentials as necessary

## Remove the psql script
rm $PSQL_SCRIPT
```

You'll need to edit the `psql` line in the script to connect to your database.  The script could also be enhanced to take the database and account credentials as arguments.

Comment: I like @Abelisto's solution much better, if it works.  I think he should make it an answer, instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution is correct, but I had Windows and had to make it run via a batch (command) file. Posting it here if someone needs that

```
@echo off

echo 'Reading file %1'
set CONN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\psql.exe" -U dbusername -d mydbname
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sed.exe" 's/;//g;/^--/ d;s/--.*//g;' %1 | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tr.exe" '\n' ' ' > c:\temp\query.txt
set /p QUERY=<c:\temp\query.txt
echo %QUERY%

echo \copy (%QUERY%) to '%2' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER) | %CONN%
```