# Batch file for reading sql scripts from file and export results to csv

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I want to make a batch file that will get query from .SQL script from the directory and export results in .csv format. I need to connect to the Postgres server.

So I'm trying to do this using that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39049102/9631920.
My file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sql_to_csv.sh
echo test1
CONN="psql -U my_user -d my_db -h host -port"
QUERY="$(sed 's/;//g;/^--/ d;s/--.*//g;' 'folder/folder/folder/file.sql' | tr '\n' ' ')"
echo test2
echo "$QUERY"
echo test3
echo "\\copy ($QUERY) to 'folder/folder/folder/file.csv' with csv header" | $CONN > /dev/null
echo query in progress
```

It shows me script from query and test3 and then stops. What am I doing wrong?

edit.
My file:

```
#!/bin/bash

PSQL = "psql -h 250.250.250.250 -p 5432 -U user -d test"

${PSQL} << OMG2

CREATE TEMP VIEW xyz AS
`cat C:\Users\test\Documents\my_query.sql`
        ;

\copy (select * from xyz) TO 'C:\Users\test\Documents\res.csv';

OMG2
```

But it's not asking password, and not getting any result file

Comment: It's reading and creating the result file now. But the result file is empty. Can't understand why, tried on 3 different scripts

Comment: What is in `folder/folder/folder/file.sql` ? Just a single query?

Comment: Complex single select query

Comment: Put it into a TEMP view and `\copy (select * from the_view) TO 'the_file.csv'; (no need to remove comments, or put everything on a single line!)

Comment: So I need to create temp view for every script? I think it's not possible because every time I need a new script to complete

Comment: The TEMP view will be dropped automatically when the script/session ends.

Comment: I am assuming there is a `~/pgpass` file with the correct login/password for the DB you need, so it is not supposed to ask for a password. And the `<<OMG` upto the single line with `OMG2` is a shell here-document. It basically functions as the standard input for the executed program. (here: psql)

Comment: BTW: you suddenly have backslashes in you pathname. These might confuse the shell.

Answer (score 1):

- a shell HERE-document will solve most of your quoting woes
- a temp view will solve the single-query-on-a-single line problem

Example (using a multi-line two-table JOIN):

---

```
#!/bin/bash

PSQL="psql -U www twitters"

${PSQL} << OMG

        -- Some comment here
CREATE TEMP VIEW xyz AS
SELECT twp.name, twt.*
FROM tweeps twp
JOIN tweets twt
        ON twt.user_id = twp.id
        AND twt.in_reply_to_id > 3
WHERE 1=1
AND (False OR  twp.screen_name ilike '%omg%' )
        ;

\copy (select * from xyz) TO 'omg.csv';

OMG
```

---

If you want the contents of an existing .sql file, you can cat it inside the here document, using a backtick-expansion:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

PSQL="psql -X -n -U www twitters"

${PSQL} << OMG2

        -- Some comment here
CREATE TEMP VIEW xyz AS
-- ... more comment
-- cat the original file here
`cat /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/myscript.sql`
        ;

\copy (select * from xyz) TO 'omg.csv';

OMG2
```

Comment: CREATE TEMP VIEW xyz AS \i folder/folder/folder/file.sql?

Comment: Yes, but inside the HERE-document, and on a separate line.

Comment: Sorry, psql won't allow `\include` accross statement boundaries.

Comment: Tried to make it like your last edit, and can't get any result using .sh file. It's creating some postgress command in bash and closing it in a moment

Comment: Maybe you missed the backtics inside the here-document? (it worked here)

Comment: Added example in question. I can't understand what << OMG2 doing, is this working like alias?